# show database longs and lats on google map

Tags: php

I got latitude,longitude and address from the database. How to show each store values on google map:

```
 $qry = mysqli_query($link,"select * from store");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
 $lat = $row['lat'];
 $long = $row['lng'];
 $adresse = $row['Adresse'];
 }
```

How to show each store with the address one after another on google map.In my code, it only shows one map.how to show each map?

Comment: Where's your javascript to produce the map?

Comment: Actually what you can do with **PHP** is to create an **array or Json object** that you will **loop through in Javascript** to create your **markers**... and you can't do this with PHP alone!

Answer (score 0):

```
        //JS function

    window.onload=initMap;

     function initMap() {

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 4,             
            });
           show_markers();
          }
/*
Considering you have php array with locations
in format ('address'=>add1,'lat'=>lat1,'lng'=>lng1)
$qry = mysqli_query($link,"select * from store");
$marker_data = mysqli_fetch_array($qry);
*/



     function show_markers(){
         var locations = <?php echo json_encode($marker_data);?>;

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i]['lat'], locations[i]['lng']),
            map: map
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i]['address']);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
    }
```

reffer map related code :https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map